# Calculating the factorial of a number efficiently

Tags: java, performance

I was trying to calculate the factorial of a large number in a short time:

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader keyboard=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
        while(n!=0){
            int uptoValue=Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
            calculateFactorial(uptoValue);
            n--;
        }
    }
    private static void calculateFactorial(int uptoValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigInteger answer=new BigInteger("1");
        for(int i=1;i<=uptoValue;i++){
            answer=answer.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Which gave me total sum of  running  time of 1.7618 against various inputs.

Now I tried to solve it using pattern decomposition to avoid the number of loops, and wrote the following code:

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader keyboard=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
        while(n!=0){
            int uptoValue=Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
            calculateFactorial(uptoValue);
            n--;
        }
    }
    private static void calculateFactorial(int uptoValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigInteger answer=new BigInteger("1");
        boolean oddUptoValue=false;
        int tempUptoValue=0;
        if(uptoValue%2!=0){
            tempUptoValue=uptoValue-1;
            oddUptoValue=true;
        }else{
            tempUptoValue=uptoValue;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<=tempUptoValue/2;i++){
            int temp=(tempUptoValue-i+1)*i;
            answer=answer.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(temp)));
        }
        if(oddUptoValue){
            answer=answer.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(uptoValue)));
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Which gave me a total sum of running time of 1.6362 sec against various inputs.

How can I improve the runtime? What are more efficient algorithms to calculate the factorials of a large number?

Comment: Also see these articles: https://sites.google.com/site/examath/research/factorials and http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: @RobAu the pattern one that has been mentioned i figured it out already .. .. Thanks for the other ways and links :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I improve the runtime? What are more efficient algorithms to calculate the factorials of a large number?

If you really want to know it, then study [BigIntegerMath.factorial](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fa95e381e665d8ee9639543b99ed38020c8de5ef/guava/src/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.java#L316) from Guava. There are too many tricks there to be described here.

### Review

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Are you sure you need it?

```
    boolean oddUptoValue=false;
    int tempUptoValue=0;
    if(uptoValue%2!=0){
        tempUptoValue=uptoValue-1;
        oddUptoValue=true;
    }else{
        tempUptoValue=uptoValue;
    }
```

Too complicated. What about

```
boolean oddUptoValue = uptoValue % 2 != 0;
```

and leaving `oddUptoValue` alone, as the division by two rounds down anyway.

```
int temp=(tempUptoValue-i+1)*i;
```

This can overflow, use

```
long product = (tempUptoValue - i + 1L) * i;
```

Note the name, the formatting (spacing), and the use of `1L` which enforces a cast to `long` of both multiplicands.

```
 answer=answer.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(temp)));
```

This should be

```
 answer = answer.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(product));
```

### Optimizations

Despite avoiding the conversion via string being much faster, my above changes won't help with speed. The vast majority of the time for big inputs get spend in the `BigInteger` multiplication.

The simplest trick is getting rid of powers of two. Use `Integer.numberofTrailingZeros` for removing them from each multiplicand, compute the product and finally shift it left. This way the numbers you deal with get smaller and all operations get faster.

Regrouping the operands is the second trick. For four about equally big numbers, computing

```
(a * b) * (c * d)
```

instead of

```
((a * b) * c) *d
```

gives you a nice speedup. You can regroup your operands to make use of this.

Comment: finally shift it left by the number of zeros right ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand [Sure](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fa95e381e665d8ee9639543b99ed38020c8de5ef/guava/src/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.java#L368).

Comment: instead of this `(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(temp))` this line `(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(temp))`  itself reduce my time to 1.4937 secs .. Thanks :)

Comment: @AnkurAnand Then you're working with smaller numbers than I supposed as for bigger ones the multiplications dominate. You should add the benchmark to the review next time.

Answer (score 5):

All of the `new BigInteger(String.valueOf(…))` calls should be replaced by `BigInteger.valueOf(…)`. Also, `new BigInteger("1")` is just `BigInteger.ONE`.

Your second method is faster because it's halving the number of `BigInteger` multiplications by doing some of them using `int` multiplication. The `int` multiplication should be done using `long` to store the result, to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 3):

One of many ways is dividing n by 2 repeatedly.

$$n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot  \ldots  \cdot n$$

We define \$\mathrm{factodd}(n)\$ as the product of odd numbers 1∙3∙5∙…∙n:

$$\begin{align}
n! &= \mathrm{factodd}(n) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot  \ldots   \cdot \frac{n}{2}\right) \\
   &= \mathrm{factodd}(n) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{4}} \cdot \left(1 \cdot 2 \cdot  \ldots  \cdot \frac{n}{4}\right)\right) \\
   &\ \vdots \\
   &= \mathrm{factodd}(n) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{4}}\left(\mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{8}}\left(\mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{8}\right) \cdot  \ldots \right)\right)\right) \\
   &= 2^{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{4}+...+\frac{n}{2^k}} \cdot \mathrm{factodd}(n) \cdot \mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \cdot \mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{2^2}\right) \cdot \mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{2^3}\right) \cdot  \ldots  \cdot \mathrm{factodd}\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)
\end{align}$$

where \$k\$ is the nearest biggest exponent of 2 which satisfies \$\dfrac{n}{2^k}=1\$, means \$k=log_{2}{n}\$

Notice that you don't have to calculate factodd(k) each time — just multiply the square of the factorial of common first n/2 numbers of factodd(n) * factodd(n/2) by (n/2+1)∙(n/2+3)…n and so on.

The overall expression should look somewhat like:

$$2^{n(1-{\frac{1}{2}}^{log_{2}{n}})}  \cdot 3^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{3}}+1} \cdot 5^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{5}}+1} \cdot 7^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{7}}+1} \ldots$$

---

A more naïve way (but not recommended) is to extract all \$2^k \cdot 5^{k'}\$ factors and multiply them separately.

Example:

1∙2∙3∙4∙5∙6∙…∙100,

M={2,5,2*2,2*5,5*5,2*2*2,2*2*5,2*5*5,2*2*5*5}

Multiplication of all these numbers isn't required, because we can instead calculate how many couples of (2,5) are there and then append as much zeroes to the remaining product.

---

Just by combining first and second methods together I came up with a conclusion:

$$\begin{align}
n! &= 2^{n-1}*5^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{5}}+1} \cdot 3^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{3}}+1} \cdot 7^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{7}}+1} \ldots \ldots \\
   &= 10^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{5}}+1} \cdot 2^{n-log_{2}{\frac{n}{5}}-2} \cdot 3^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{3}}+1} \cdot  7^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{7}}+1} \ldots \ldots
\end{align}$$

This is equal to: \$ \cdot 2^{n-log_{2}{\frac{n}{5}}-2} \cdot 3^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{3}}+1} \cdot  7^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{7}}+1} \ldots \ldots x^{log_{2}{\frac{n}{x}}+1}\$ after \$ log_{2}{\frac{n}{5}}+1 \$ trailing zeroes with \$x\$ the last odd factor of \$n!\$

---

**Hardcore way**:

I named it so because of its deep arborescent structure, and it takes huge memory amount, but it gives out the **least** calculation of multiplying prime factors by their exponents.

First, we must build a very-ramified tree starting from the first prime number 2 until n.

[image]

- Arcs are \$prime^e\$ of \$x^e\$ step  where \$x\$ is the actual prime, and \$e\$ is next stage. We build the tree of prime \$x=2\$ first, and we stop when \$e\$ exceeds \$n\$.
- Lines are:

  Red lines are of step=4 where prime number \$x=2\$ is always of exponent \$e= 1\$

  Generally we define all points where exponent of actual prime is constant:       \$2^e(2k+1)\$ (e=2 green line), where \$k\$ is the actual step looked forward, and \$e\$ is constant exponent.

  After this we highlight next prime \$x=3\$, and we do same process of tree-expanding of \$3^e(3k+1)\$ (e=1 yellow line) and \$3^e(3k+2)\$ (e=1 blue line) after all arcs of \$3^k\$ are developed.

  - Once we come across an arc-node, we add the actual \$k\$ to the prime exponent at the level of the root of the tree. In general we have \$prime^{1+2+..+k}=prime^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}\$.
  - Once we come across a line we just add the actual constant to all exponents of tree-roots which are linked to the actual number pointed by same lines, as a whole we have \$prime^{e+e+e+e} = prime^{e(k+1)}\$ where \$e\$ is the line attributed exponent.

**The overall expression would look like:**

- **Arcs**: \$ 2^{\sum {log_2{n}}}*3^{\sum log_3{n}}*...*x^{\sum log_x{n}} \$ where \$x\$ is the last biggest prime factor of \$n\$
- **Lines**:

  - Red lines: \$2^{(n-2)/4}\$
  - Green lines \$2^{(n-4)/8}\$

  (x=2): \$2^{(n-2^e)/2^{e+1}}\$

In general: \$ x^{(n-x^e.l)/x^{e+1}} \$ while \$(n-lx^e)>0 \ and \ e>0 \ and \ l<x \$

So it is:

$$n! = \prod x^{\frac{(1+log_x{n})log_x{n}}{2}} * \prod \sum_{l=1} \sum_{e=1} x^{(n-x^e.l)/x^{e+1}}$$

With the biggest \$e\$ and \$l\$ which gives \$(n-lx^e)>0 \ \ and \ l<x \$ and all \$x\$ prime factors of n (correct me if I was wrong).

The memory issue can be reduced if we use [prime generating polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html) but it seems you can't generate up to first 1681 primes using [Euler polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerPrime.html). So it remains risky to engage in that with factorials bigger than 1681!

Comment: Shouldn't \$n! = \mathrm{factodd}(n) \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot  \ldots   \cdot \frac{n}{2}\right) \$ be \$n!=\mathrm{factodd}(n)\cdot 2 \cdot \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor !\$?

Comment: @EmilyL. you are going backward here , but ur last expression is false

Comment: @correction \$ n!=factodd(n).2^{n/2}.(n/2)! \$

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense actually. But you still need the floor operator otherwise you get a \$\sqrt{2}\$ and factorial of a fraction for odd \$n\$.

Comment: @EmilyL. the floor operation is incomparable next to multiplication of 99999 consecutive integers :D

Comment: It's about mathematical correctness in your expressions, not performance. The floor is implicit when you do integer division.

Comment: @EmilyL. its not a big deal , i dont know much latex so you are welcom to edit my post in non altering way (well you can correct any error of mine)

Comment: Im struggling harder to finish my expression theorically , when its done from all sides , i switch to C code

Comment: How is this answer a code review? It reviews nothing.... instead it proposes an alternate solution which is unclear, and probably does not work..... Code Review answers are not the place to dump interesting algorithms for problems.... ***unless*** the implementation is tied back to the original question in a way that explains how the original code can be improved. Just dumping code is useless, and dumping partial mathematical formula of unknown correctness is worse.

Comment: Note, this answer has now been auto-flagged by "community" for being edited more than 10 times by the author: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229025/241497

Answer (score 2):

A non-mathematical way to speed up your code, at the cost of increasing its complexity and memory usage, is to *precompute* likely inputs.

If you are likely to get inputs that are, say 100 or smaller, just compute the result for 0 through 100 once and put the results in an array; then if you are asked for one of those, you already have the result without calculating it. (Remember, it's not going to change from run to run; you can compute them *once*, print out the results, and then use that to put *literals* into your source code.)

Or, suppose the maximum value you are likely to get as an input is 1000. Compute the factorials of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... 1024 and put those in an array. When you are asked for the factorial of 600, say, you already have the factorial of 512 computed, so you've cut down the number of multiplications by around 80% right there.

Or, you can do memoization. Suppose you are asked for the factorial of 600 first. Make a map from inputs to outputs and compute the factorial of every number from 1 through 600 and put it in the map. Then the second time you are called, if the caller wants a value less than 600, you've already got it in the map, and if they want a value greater than 600, you can at least start with 600, and put more things in your map as you go.